# Extract Outlook delivery failure email subjects and recepients using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, window, ms-office

I used to send thousands of  mails over outlook and many since many recipient leave th org, used to get delivery failure mail.

In order to correct my list I want to extract subject and recipient to filter my master list.

The issue is that my .net program is able to fetch mail subject it's not able to fetch the recipient. Since Recipient is not available in To/CC/BCC list but in mail body, I have to read mail body and will subsequently fetch the email-id.

Using below code however this is not reading the CC list from the mail body.

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ReportItem item = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder = null;


        try
        {
            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            ns = app.GetNamespace("IPM.Note");
            ns.Logon (null, null, false, false);
            inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            subFolder = inboxFolder.Folders["TestMail"]; //folder.Folders[1]; also works
            //MessageBox.Show("Folder Name: " + subFolder.Name, subFolder.EntryID);
            //MessageBox.Show("Num Items:  " + subFolder.Items.Count.ToString());

            for(int i=1;i<=subFolder.Items.Count;i++)
              {                   
                item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ReportItem)subFolder.Items[i];                

               //var item = subFolder.Items[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}", i.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", item.Subject);
                //Console.WriteLine("Receipient: {0}", item); 
                Console.WriteLine("Categories: {0}", item.Categories);
                Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", item.Body);
                Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", item.BillingInformation);
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.Subject);                       

              }
        }
        catch(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

The subject is appearing something in gibberish and unreadable format.

Also the item.To/CC/bcc is not exposed.

Any help/suggestion pls...

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following method before to extract email addresses from a body of an delivery failure email message:

```
private IList<string> FindEmailAddresses(string body)
{
    IList<string> emailAddresses = new List<string>;
    string emailMatch = @"\b([A-Z0-9._%-]+)@([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})\b";

    Regex mailReg = new Regex(emailMatch,
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    MatchCollection matches = mailReg.Matches(body);

    for (int index = 0; index < matches.Count; index++)
    {
        emailAddresses.Add(matches[index].ToString());
    }

    return emailAddresses;
}
```

A couple of notes:

The regex used is fairly simple and will catch the more simply formatted emails but can miss more complex formatted addresses.

I usually deal with the MailItem objects of the delivery failure emails.  I haven't worked with ReportItem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could setup your mail server to send you the list of failed email addresses